# Is there a quicker method for returning a sublist after a certain index of a list in Java?

Tags: java, collections, list

I'm working on a program in which I will need to frequently truncate the beginning of a list, by just a few indices. (Sometimes, only one.) Then, the new list must be passed on to another method, which will likely end up doing the same thing.

Obviously I want this to be done as efficiently as possible. There is an obvious answer in the way of functionality:

```
for(int i = «intended index»; i < list.size(); i++) newList.add(list.get(i));
nextMethod(newList);
```

However, the theta notation is rather horrific. I would prefer something like:

```
List newList = list.subset(«intended index», list.size());
```

But I can't find anything like that.

I have the feeling that maximum and minimum list indexes might be handled by pointers. Is there such a method in, say, Collections, which will allow me to create a list that references a subset of the exact same data? Or should I give up on that and focus on changing some other part of my algorithm? Or is a List the wrong collection to use?

Comment: did you even look in the API? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29

Comment: That's definitely part of my solution. As to why I didn't "look in the API", I did; the API is big, and I'm not sure why I would be looking at the JavaSE 6 API, anyway…

The remaining concern is that the algorithm that I am building does require structural changes. Am I to understand that the sublist may be structurally changed, but the original list is not structurally changed until the sublist is no longer in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here. First, the API does offer a [subList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method.

If the lists are immutable or are not modified, you can simply use the `subList()` method directly. Similar to iterators, they will fail fast if the list is structurally changed (i.e. the size changes among other things).

If you need multiple views into the same list to allow concurrent modifications, you will need to use a [concurrent list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead. The performance is fairly bad, and not all views (sublist, iterator) will see the updated data, but it is safe. Since performance appears to be a concern of yours I would try to avoid this if possible, even if it means refactoring your code to avoid it. This is typically used with true concurrency, i.e. threads, and only when better data structures are not appropriate.

Comment: sublist provides a view into the List, ArrayList does this by offsetting the index passed in each time and linked list just keeps the pointers to the ends of the sublist

Comment: Thanks @ratchetfreak for as long as I have been using Java I never realized that. Regardless, I think mutability is still the primary concern here, and the question is not clear whether or not the _contents_ of the list change as opposed to viewing a sublist.

Comment: Thankfully, I only need to operate on one sublist at a time; this is basically for nodes of a parser tree for a translator. I won't need multiple views. But for a sublist, just as a point of clarity, I understand that I cannot alter the structure of the original list. Am I to understand that I can alter the structure of the sublist, and these alterations will also apply to the original? As if that is the case, I may have a solution.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin yes, changes to the sublist show up in the parent: the same internal data structure backs both. My understanding from reading the JavaDoc is that you can do anything with the sublist, the only restriction is structural modifications of the parent _through_ the parent list reference. Same thing as with iterators.